# how to solve move_uploaded_file(img/loja.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload

this is error getting from upload images, the images cant move and permission denied, I have also configured the directory but still same.
anyone has an idea please help

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(img/t-shirts-1.jpg): failed to open
>   stream: Warning:Permission denied in
>   /var/www/html/wp_inventori/edit.php on line 25 move_uploaded_file():
>   Unable to move '/tmp/phpUIcxe5' to 'img/t-shirts-1.jpg' in
>   /var/www/html/wp_inventori/edit.php on line 25

```
if(isset($_FILES['imagen']['name']) && ($_FILES['imagen']['name']!="")){
    $target_dir = "img/";
    $file = $_FILES['imagen']['name'];
    $path = pathinfo($file);
    $filename = $path['filename'];
    $ext = $path['extension'];
    $temp_name = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
    $path_filename_ext = $target_dir.$filename.".".$ext;
if (file_exists($path_filename_ext)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    }else{
       move_uploaded_file($temp_name,$path_filename_ext);
       echo "Congratulations! File Uploaded Successfully.";
   }
```

Comment: Are you sure this directory exists and if it does the user running the your application or the user running your web server has the correct rights to move this file to this location?

Comment: Try using fullpath for $target_dir

Comment: Dear all I been changing permission and changing the user but the result still same, I have following all answer, currently, I using root and changed to apache also same doesn't solve out. any idea??

Comment: i have solved with this : sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/images -R